# Call C# function from C++, how to pass parameter to C# function

Tags: c#, c++, dll, parameters

I want to create a C# dll, then I'd like to call C# function from C++ with the following prototype:

`setVal(DWORD id, BYTE* msginstime, BYTE* data);`

I have not known how to pass `id, msginstime, data` parameters to C# function yet.
(or the way C# function get parameters from C++ function).

I read this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/InterOp.aspx
but this example does not pass parameters.

Would you please give any hints on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know what the question is here. Do you want someone to write the code for you? The article you read seems like it's a perfectly good introduction. Have you tried doing this? What went wrong? Did you see an error? Did the program crash? A simpler alternative is to write an application using C++/CLI; that makes interfacing with C# code much easier. Is there any way that's an option for you?

Comment: I'd like to know the way to pass and get parameters between C# and C++. So do you have any hint?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't read the article to which you link. That does what you ask.

Comment: This example use get{}. I declared interface function, and wrote function in class as normal. It works fine. Thank you a lot!